# Cocoa/iPad Inserting new view...what am I doing wrong

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview

Sorry for wanting to ask a simple question.

I have my initial view loaded in the main view controller (TestViewController). The plan is to replace that view with the view from another controller (PageOneViewController). Both views live in the same Nib but are linked to outlets in their respective controllers.

When it comes to running the program, I press the button, the view disappears but nothing replaces it. I must have misunderstood something. By my understanding, it should work. What am I doing wrong?

```
@class PageOneViewController;

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {

}

- (void) addPageOne;
- (IBAction) pressButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

...

```
#import "TestViewController.h"
#import "PageOneViewController.h"


@implementation TestViewController

- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender  {

 [self addPageOne];

}

- (void) addPageOne {

 PageOneViewController *pageOne = [PageOneViewController alloc];
 [self.view removeFromSuperview];
 [self.view insertSubview:pageOne.view atIndex:0]; 
 [pageOne release];   

}

- (void)dealloc
{...
```

...

```
@interface PageOneViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIView *view;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *view;

@end
```

...

```
#import "PageOneViewController.h"

@implementation PageOneViewController

@synthesize view;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `removeFromSuperview` causes the first view to no longer be displayed. Then you add the second view on top of the first view, but since view 1 still isn't being displayed the user can't see either one.  You should either keep the first view visible and just cover it up with the second view, or, preferably, have a blank superview that contains either view1 or view2 as a subview depending on which one the program needs.

Comment: I've done some investigation and it looks like pageOne.view is == NULL. Not sure why. I've relinked it to the UIView outlet but no joy. I expect it's something very basic.

Comment: You don't seem to be initializing pageOne after you allocate it.

Comment: Ouch! Still, with the line amended to: PageOneViewController *pageOne = [[PageOneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil]; ...pageOne.view remains == NULL.